# Extracting matches with the original case used in the pattern during a case insensitive search

Tags: python, regex

While doing a regex pattern match, we get the content which has been a match. What if I want the pattern which was found in the content?

See the below example:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile('ERP|Gap', re.I)
>>> string = 'ERP is integral part of GAP, so erp can never be ignored, ErP!'
>>> r.findall(string)
['ERP', 'GAP', 'erp', 'ErP']
```

but I want the output to look like this : `['ERP', 'Gap', 'ERP', 'ERP']`

Because if I do a group by and sum on the original output, I would get the following output as a dataframe:

```
ERP 1
erp 1
ErP 1
GAP 1
gap 1
```

But what if I want the output to look like

```
ERP 3
Gap 2
```

in par with the keywords I am searching for?

**MORE CONTEXT**

I have a keyword list like this: `['ERP', 'Gap']`. I have a string like this: `"ERP, erp, ErP, GAP, gap"`

I want to take count of number of times each keyword has appeared in the string. Now if I am doing a pattern matching, I am getting the following output: `[ERP, erp, ErP, GAP, gap]`.

Now if I want to aggregate and take a count, I am getting the following dataframe:

```
ERP 1
erp 1
ErP 1
GAP 1
gap 1
```

While I want the output to look like this:

```
ERP 3
Gap 2
```

Comment: Read the python `re` manual at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html
Another `re` tutorial that you may find useful: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-regular-expression-tutorial
Also, https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: As far as I'm aware which part of a pattern exactly matched each substring is *not* exposed. It might be helpful to provide some more context on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I have updated the question, can you please have a look and let me know if it makes sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may build the pattern dynamically to include indices of the words you search for in the group names and then grab those pattern parts that matched:

```
import re

words = ["ERP", "Gap"]
words_dict = { f'g{i}':item for i,item in enumerate(words) } 

rx = rf"\b(?:{'|'.join([ rf'(?P<g{i}>{item})' for i,item in enumerate(words) ])})\b"

text = 'ERP is integral part of GAP, so erp can never be ignored, ErP!'

results = []
for match in re.finditer(rx, text, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
    results.append( [words_dict.get(key) for key,value in match.groupdict().items() if value][0] )

print(results) # => ['ERP', 'Gap', 'ERP', 'ERP']
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/nDtley)

The pattern will look like `\b(?:(?P<g0>ERP)|(?P<g1>Gap))\b`:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group encapsulating pattern parts:

  - `(?P<g0>ERP)` - Group "g0": `ERP`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?P<g1>Gap)` - Group "g1": `Gap`
- `)` - end of the group
- `\b` - a word boundary.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yfywOx/1).

Note `[0]` with `[words_dict.get(key) for key,value in match.groupdict().items() if value][0]` will work in all cases since when there is a match, only one group matched.

Answer (score -3):

Refer comments above.
Try:

```
>>> [x.upper() for x in r.findall(string)]
['ERP', 'GAP', 'ERP', 'ERP']
>>>
```

OR

```
>>> map(lambda x: x.upper(), r.findall(string))
['ERP', 'GAP', 'ERP', 'ERP']
>>>
```

Comment: I get it what you're trying to do, but I am not exactly wanting the same, I have updated the question a bit for better clarification. I want the exact case what is their in the pattern, and not any upper or lower case values